# Post result of scripts calculation to Teams

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have what should be a basic task but I can't figure it out. I have an Excel attachment that comes in by email every week. It has a large amount of data and I run an office script on it to find errors/missing data, which I display in a small table. I then want to post this to a Teams Channel. The idea is that I warn users of an issue before the management meeting, so they can correct them. Win/win right?

My script works fine but I can't get Power Automate to recognize the output data. It only seems to recognize data in tables, but if I create a table and ask Power Automate to 'list rows present in a table' it just states that the table doesn't exist (it doesn't, but it will when my script completes).

I did manage to automate a teams message from a static table, so thought I could just update that table. However, office scripts doesn't seem to have the functionality to copy data between one workbook and another and Power Automate can't read the data anyway. I even tried turning it into JSON, but couldn't figure out how to get Power Automate to read the JSON.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you share the Power Automate flow and the script code?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I was able to do this by using scripts to create an array in Excel and then the following code to turn it into JSON and return it:

```
let result: string = JSON.stringify(tblRangeValues);
return result;
```

Then I got Power automate to run a script on a different workbook that had a pre-existing table. Here, I parsed the JSON back to an array:

```
let tableValuesArray: string[][] = JSON.parse(tableValues);
```

I pasted the data on top of an existing table, which Power Automate could recognize (as it existing before the routine began running). I then used Power Automate to send a Teams message based on the data. The PA flow is below:

[image: Power Automate Flow]